# Can't put my Error template outside the error folder

Tags: phoenix-framework

I created a standard not_found page that is working OK as long as I have it inside the "web/templates/error" folder (`not_found.html.eex`).
I'm using (in `error_view.ex`):

```
  def render("404.html", _assigns) do
    render("not_found.html", %{})
  end
```

When I try to move it into another folder (in this particular case the standard "web/templates/page" folder) I get the `"Server internal error"` message that is suppose to appear because no render clause matches or no template is found. The template is there and I've tried with different folders.
I'm using this render function in `error_view.ex`:

```
def render("404.html", _assigns) do
  render("MyProject.PageView", "not_found.html", %{})
end
```

Shouldn't this work?

Comment: Are you using `"MyProject.PageView"` if so then you are using a string. You should use the module name (`MyProject.PageView`)

Comment: Urrggg! So stupid because I WAS looking into the documentation (http://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.View.html#render/3) and I missed that...Thank you so much for your help Gazler. Don't you want to turn this into an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [render/3](http://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.View.html#render/3) function takes 3 arguments. The first argument should be the module to call `render` on:

```
def render("404.html", _assigns) do
  render(MyProject.PageView, "not_found.html", %{})
end
```

You have provided the string `"MyProject.PageView"` instead of the module `MyProject.PageView`.